Parameters to FilterView from template redirect
I've read through all similar Q&As but can't figure out how to achieve what I'm wanting.
My base.html has a dropdown menu based on academic years:
    <div class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="d-flex align-items-center text-white text-decoration-none dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        <svg class="bi pe-none me-2" width="16" height="16"><use xlink:href="#archive"/></svg>
        <strong>Select Year</strong>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark text-small shadow">
        {% for year in years %}
                          <li><a class="dropdown-item"href="{% url 'administration.home_selected' year %}">{{year}}</a></li>
                          {% endfor %}

      </ul>
    </div>

administration.home_selected is a function based view and receives the parameter of year to show the desired data relating to that academic year:
url.py
path(
        "home_selected/<int:year>",
        views.home_selected,
        name="administration.home_selected",
    ),

How do I replicate the same functionality when a navigation tabs within the home_selected.html is selected and relates a FilterView:
    path(
        "learners/<int:year>",
        views.FilteredLearnerListView.as_view(),
        name="administration.learners",
    ),

The view is currently coded to show only current year data but I'd like to be able to do the same as I have with the function based view to show the correct data depending on the year selected from the base.html
views.py
class FilteredLearnerListView(SingleTableMixin, FilterView):
    table_class = LearnerTable
    model = Learner
    context_object_name = "learner_list"

    current = AcademicYear.objects.filter(is_current=True).get()
    contracts_list = Contract.objects.filter(academic_year=current).values_list(
        "id", flat=True
    )
    contracts_list = list(contracts_list)
    contracts = Contract.objects.filter(academic_year=current).values()
    groups = Group.objects.filter(contractId__in=contracts_list)
    queryset = Learner.objects.filter(groupId__in=groups)
    template_name = "learner_list.html"

    filterset_class = LearnerFilter

filters.py
class LearnerFilter(FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Learner
        fields = {"surname": ["iexact"], "groupId": ["exact"]}

Please forgive any beginner errors. I'm eager to learn.

ffffYou are making queries in the class definition?

Can you also share your models?

This isn't very clear. If you want the selection in the menu to be an input to the filter, you would declare it in the filterset_class (and you'd probably need to override your base.html since a FilterView does its own thing). Alternatively you can interrogate request.GET in your view to access the base.html selected value, and code what to do with it. Perhaps use it to pre-filter the queryset that the FilterView which then further filters it as requested by the  user.
